# How to check if an element has a class using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm attempting to use javascript to determine whether an element has a class and then remove it, but I can't seem to get it to work.

the class name **show** has the property `display: block;`

```js
var drop = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown');
var link = document.getElementsByClassName('faculties')
var i


for (let i = 0; i < link.length; i++) {
  link[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
      var present = drop.classList.contains('show');
      if (present == true) {
        // drop.classList.remove('show')
        alert('hi')
        drop[i].classList.toggle("show");

      });
  }
```

```html
<div class="right programmes">
  <div class="widget">
    <h1>Our Programmes and Courses</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="widget">
    <div class="faculties">
      <a>Faculty of Physical Sciences <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <h1>Faculty Stuff</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="faculties">
      <a>Faculty of Biological Sciences <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <h1>Faculty Stuff</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="faculties">
      <a>Faculty of Health Sciences <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <h1>Faculty Stuff</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `drop.classList.contains('show')` UM, drop is an html Collection and you are trying to read the classList? You can not do that. You would need to loop over the collection.

Comment: In your code, `var present = drop.classList.contains('show')`, you will get getting classList of undefined. change it as `var present = drop[i].classList.contains('show')`.

Comment: @epascarello I know that
I'm trying to get it to remove the class show from all the elements then when I click, only the one I clicked on will have the class attached to it

Comment: Well you can not work on a collection, so you need to either change how you find the selected element, or you have to loop.

Comment: Which element *precisely* is to be made visible on click? The dropdown that is contained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to work off a HTML Collection and it does not work that way. You need to either loop over the collection or find the element with the class.

**Loop**

```
for (var j=0; j < drop.length; j++) {
  if(j!==i) drop[j].classList.remove("show");
}
drop[i].classList.toggle('show');
```

**Select**

```
// Select the element with a new selector
const active = document.querySelector(".programmes .dropdown.show");
// Make sure it is not the current thing you clicked on
if (active && active !== drop[i]) {
  active.classList.remove('show');
}
drop[i].classList.toggle('show');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `hidden` here (and add that as a boolean attribute on your HTML to reflect initial state):

```js
const faculties = document.querySelectorAll('.faculties');
const dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown');

for (const faculty of faculties) {
  faculty.addEventListener('click', e => {
    for (const dropdown of dropdowns) {
      dropdown.hidden = ![...faculty.children].includes(dropdown);
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="right programmes">
  <div class="widget">
    <h1>Our Programmes and Courses</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="widget">
    <div class="faculties">
      <a>Faculty of Physical Sciences <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
      <div class="dropdown" hidden>
        <h1>Faculty Stuff</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="faculties">
      <a>Faculty of Biological Sciences <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
      <div class="dropdown" hidden>
        <h1>Faculty Stuff</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="faculties">
      <a>Faculty of Health Sciences <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
      <div class="dropdown" hidden>
        <h1>Faculty Stuff</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```